# ASP.NET ascx.cs via GET

Tags: asp.net, security, iis

Say I have this url:
http://site.example/dir/

In this folder I have these files: `test.ascx.cs` and `test.ascx`

Just to be clear, I am not a .NET developer.

From a security point of view - why can't I access http://site.example/dir/test.ascx.cs and how secure is it to keep those files there?

I assume IIS filters out request that query these kind of files, but can someone explain me this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register ASP.NET with IIS ([aspnet_regiis.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-2.0/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.80))) it will add common extensions and associate them with the ASP.NET handler. As far as the `.cs` extension is concerned it is filtered and not served by IIS. It is absolutely safe to have these files there, but I would recommend you to use an ASP.NET application project (in contrast to ASP.NET website) which is precompiled and you don't need to deploy source code files on your server.

[image]
<sub>(source: [wewill.cn](http://www.wewill.cn/upload/2007_07/070731225072981.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You just explained it yourself. IIS won't serve those files.

Comment: How about having those files there? Isn't there a way to "compile" them and than deploy? Is it safe to have those files there?

Comment: @Heavy: yes, don't use "web site projects". Always use "Add->New Project" to add a web application project. It compiles all such files into a single DLL. But it's not a security problem. If the server won't serve them, then it's not an issue.